# How can one do change of variables for solutions to a staochastic partial differential equation?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, linear-pde

isHow can one do change of variables for solutions to a staochastic partial differential equation? For example, let us consider the following stochastic transport equation:
$$
dy(t,x) + y_x(t,x) + y(t,x)dB(t)=0.
$$
Here $B(\cdot)$ is a standard one dimensional Brownian motion. If we do change of variables for the solution $y(\cdot,\cdot)$, say, for example, we let $t'=t+x^2$, $x'=x$, then, is $y(t',x')$ a solution to a stochastic partial differential equation or not? If it is, what is the equation?